# Setting names of df with character vector that is a different length

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I'm having trouble setting names to a df that I have scraped from a website.  The `html_table` has a bunch of columns that don't have proper column names.  When I go to use `purrr::set_names` I get an error message since the columns scraped, are a different length than the columns on the `html_table`.  Is there a way to resolve this that anyone can think of?  The missing set of columns appear to be duplicate data.  They are identical to columns `5:10` in `data`.  Example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
# url
url <- "https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/pitchfx/leaderboards/index.php?hand=&reportType=avg&prp=P&month=&year=2019&pitch=FS&ds=&lim=0"

# get page from URL
page <-
  url %>%
  xml2::read_html()

# get df from page
data <-
  page %>%
  rvest::html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  tbl_df()

# get column names
names <-
  page %>%
  rvest::html_node("thead") %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("th") %>%
  rvest::html_text() %>%
  stringr::str_trim()

# Add Column names since Scrape does not include
df <-
  data %>%
  purrr::set_names(names)
#> `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`
Created on 2019-10-18 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `length` of `names` is not matching with the number of columns of the 'data'.  According to `?set_names`

> set_names(x, nm = x, ...)
>
> x- Vector to name.
>
> ... - Vector of names, the same length as x.

As it requires the same `length` and here it is not the case, it is throwing an error.

One option is to use `rename_at`.   If we know the column position index or column names, pass that in the `vars` of `rename_at` and change the column names

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     rename_at(seq_len(length(names)), ~ names)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a time to use set_names vs. rename_at?  Pros or cons to either approach?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz. If you want to change the whole dataset names, `set_names` is fine.  (`setnames` from `data.table` does change a subset of column names), otherwise, `rename_at` can be used (`rename_all` is also used for changing all the column names)

Comment: @Jazzmatazz. One of the pros of using `rename_at` is that it is easier to modify the existing column name by adding suffix/prefix i.e `mtcars %>% rename_at(1:2, ~ paste0(.x, "hello"))`